# How can I check the bandwidth that is using every device inside a network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, home-networking

I have issues sometimes with my connections that are a little bit weird, and for example sometimes but for short periods, I can receive information but I the send it stuck, and is not a problem of my device I think because it happens in my pc and in my smartphone, and in all the devices of my house. I don't think that is an external problem, maybe Is a problem of my own router. Anyways, what I want to do first is to find a program that can check how much bandwidth is using every device filtered by IP. For example some people say you va check this info in your own router, but that's not my case. I have studied networking and and currently I am doing it, I have CCNA1 and 2 but when it comes to real life it comes really strange and I get anxiety with all ^^''.

Comment: You tagged this with "wireless-networking". If more than one device is wireless, you need to pay attention to wireless *airtime*, not just *bandwidth*. A wireless device with an old slow radio can take hundreds of times more airtime to send the same amount of data as a device with a modern radio. If you just look at their bits or bytes per second, you would think both devices are sharing the RF medium equally, even though the slow device might be hogging 100x the airtime as the fast device.

Comment: You have many options:

 1. Use a specialized divice as next generation firewall.
 2. Enable SNMP on your access switch and monitor each port, i know you cant see which user/ip bandwidh, but you can track the source of the problem physically and discover if you have problem of collitions. Sadly in both cases you need some minimal infrastructure

Comment: @RoidRamirez All my devices are connected via the access point so I can't do that

Comment: @Tim_Stewart It is a livebox next orange (Spanish company)

Comment: What's your up/down speed from the ISP? It's been a while since a had DSL, but enabling some basic QOS should make a huge difference. You can also pick up a ddwrt or openwrt compatible router for 5-10 bucks on eBay. If you put a ddwrt box or openwrt box I front of your router it will let you view the bandwidth of each device in real time.